# Unbound dns server response throwaway when queried for local lan hostnames

Tags: dns, unbound

I'm on Windows and I have configured [Unbound](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/) to be used as DNS for the Android Emulator (since `-dns-server` doesn't seem to work*). The DNS servers are taken from the list given by `ipconfig /all`.

I can tell from Unbound logs that it is being queried for any webpage I try to browse from the emulator, but local LAN names aren't resolved, while Internet ones are.

From the logs I see nothing is returned for :

```
info: 10.241.36.145 <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN
info: resolving <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN
info: response for <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN
info: reply from <.> 10.241.11.48#53
info: query response was THROWAWAY
info: response for <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN
info: reply from <.> 10.241.11.48#53
info: query response was THROWAWAY
info: response for <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN
info: reply from <.> 10.241.11.48#53
info: query response was THROWAWAY
info: response for <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN
info: reply from <.> 10.241.11.48#53
info: query response was THROWAWAY
info: response for <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN
info: reply from <.> 10.241.11.48#53
info: query response was THROWAWAY
info: 10.241.36.145 <local-lan-server-name>. AAAA IN SERVFAIL 0.007000 0 29
```

While for a Yahoo hostname:

```
info: 10.241.36.145 www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
debug: validator[module 0] operate: extstate:module_state_initial event:module_event_new
info: validator operate: query www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
debug: iterator[module 1] operate: extstate:module_state_initial event:module_event_pass
info: resolving www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: processQueryTargets: www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: sending query: www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
debug: sending to target: <.> 10.241.6.11#53
debug: cache memory msg=70788 rrset=77712 infra=8555 val=71408
debug: iterator[module 1] operate: extstate:module_wait_reply event:module_event_reply
info: iterator operate: query www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: sanitize: removing extraneous answer RRset: atsv2-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: response for www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: reply from <.> 10.241.6.11#53
info: query response was CNAME
info: resolving www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: processQueryTargets: www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: sending query: atsv2-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
debug: sending to target: <.> 10.241.6.11#53
debug: cache memory msg=70788 rrset=77928 infra=8555 val=71408
debug: iterator[module 1] operate: extstate:module_wait_reply event:module_event_reply
info: iterator operate: query www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: iterator operate: chased to atsv2-fp-shed.wg1.b.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: response for www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
info: reply from <.> 10.241.6.11#53
info: query response was ANSWER
info: finishing processing for www.yahoo.com. AAAA IN
```

This is the configuration:

```
# Unbound configuration file on windows.
# See example.conf for more settings and syntax
server:
    # verbosity level 0-4 of logging
    verbosity: 3

    interface: 0.0.0.0
    infra-cache-min-rtt: 250
    access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 allow_snoop

    do-ip4: yes
    do-ip6: no
    do-udp: yes
    do-tcp: yes

    logfile: "C:\unbound.log"
    log-time-ascii: yes
    log-queries: yes
    log-replies: yes

    unblock-lan-zones: yes
    insecure-lan-zones: yes

    auto-trust-anchor-file: "C:\Program Files\Unbound\root.key"

forward-zone:
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 10.241.6.11
    forward-addr: 10.241.11.48
    forward-addr: 10.241.11.49
```

---

*: In fact, when I give to the emulator the same DNS ip address I configured in Unbound I get the same behaviour, local LAN names are not resolved while Internet ones (like www.yahoo.com) work.

This is what `nslookup` says about that hostname:

```
C:\> nslookup <local-lan-server-name>
Server:  <dns-server-name>
Address:  10.241.11.48

Nome:    <local-lan-server-name>
Address:  10.241.11.27
```

So I guess the DNS server configuration is correct.